# How to install Ubuntu font in .xib or can we change system default font for Xcode 4.5.1 (not through Code it should be through the .xib)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xib

Need to add Ubuntu Font through .xib , i Mean it should be like in the list for Example Font:Custom Family:Helvetica Style:Regular , Family Should be 'Ubuntu'

OR

Can We Change the system Default Font To Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have the otf file of the respective font?

Comment: Yes i have ttf file of ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not possible via XIB

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your custom font through xib --> font property means, it is not possible. But, if you want a label or textfield or etc., with your custom font means we achieve this by sub-classing the respective control i.e, overriding the `awakeFromNib`. And you need to add your custom font in the .plist file of your project under the key "*Fonts provided by application*". Like this..

[image]